# How does navigation work in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, navigation

I have one question about navigation in Stack Overflow:

> [image: This is the image]

If you mark it properly, when I am on *Tags* and I go to *Users*, the top portion will stay in touch. I.e. the top bar will stay as it is, and the middle portion navigates to *Users*. I cannot show real-time animation here, but navigation works without affecting the top portion. I am a developer, and I want to know how this can be achieved.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeDuckett What i means is all depends on a speed right?

Comment: Yes, the way Stack Overflow gives the appearance of only updating part of the page (at least in this case) is simply the fact that it loads so fast.

Comment: hmmm nice one :D

Answer (score 9):

The Stack Exchange team is very adamant about every millisecond of speed they can get. The benefit is that when you navigate using the software, you barely even notice that pages are loading.

However, they are in fact loading and so is the top bar. It is just so quick that you can't quite notice it (you may also have a high performance computer which aids in rendering).

I think you may have over thought the situation a little bit, navigating away from a page does load the top bar. Here is some proof, note that in the Http response the containing html does in fact have the topbar in it.

[image]

Comment: I think that can be achieved by some technique also

Comment: It could be achieved by doing an asynchronous javascript call to get updated HTML to insert/replace part of the page with (but as this answer shows, that's not what's happening here).